# Angular JS object scope

Tags: angularjs

I have written a simple Angular JS code which greets user depending on the time of the day. It works fine. The code is given below:

```
var modSvc = angular.module("appName",[]); 

modSvc.provider("date",function(){
    var greeting;
    return {
        showGreeting:function(value){
            greeting = value;
        },
        $get:function(){
            //it has to return an object which can have variables and functions
            return {
                showDate:function(){
                    var date = new Date();
                    return date.getHours();
                },
                showGreetingMessage:function(){                 
                    //var date = new Date();
                    return greeting + ", It's "+ this.showDate();
                }
            }
        }
    };
});

modSvc.config(function(dateProvider){
    var hours = dateProvider.$get().showDate();
    if(hours<12)
        dateProvider.showGreeting("Good morning!");
    else if(hours<17)
        dateProvider.showGreeting("Good afternoon!");
    else if(hours<22)
        dateProvider.showGreeting("Good evening!");
    else
        dateProvider.showGreeting("Good night!");
});

function serviceController($scope,date){
    $scope.greetingMessage = date.showGreetingMessage();
}

modSvc.controller("svcController",serviceController);
```

If you see `showGreetingMessage` function it has only one line of code which is:

```
return greeting + ", It's "+ this.showDate();
```

However `showDate` function resides at the same level as that of `showGreetingMessage` function. That's why `this.showDate` should not work and it should give error. But it works perfectly fine. How is it so?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the `JavaScript` engine that is used but according to the [Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) your "this" actually references the parent object since you are returning an object.

> As an object method
>
> When a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to the object the method is called on.
>
> In the following example, when o.f() is invoked, inside the function this is bound to the o object.

```
var o = {
  prop: 37,
  f: function() {
    return this.prop;
  }
};

console.log(o.f()); // logs 37
```